# Can't use regular expression to match exact string

Tags: regex

Given a string below:

```
String s = "sschk@@123456sschk@@123456gme@@100&200&300&1,2,3,4,5$6,7,8,9,0sschk@@123456";
```

I apply a pattern, `sschk@@\\d+?` or `sschk@@.+?` want to get all `sschk@@123456` and replace them with an empty string. Please note that number after `sschk@@` might different each time I got it, for example `sschk@@321321`.

But I only got

```
[sschk@@1, sschk@@1, sschk@@1]
```

What pattern should I apply to get exact each `sschk@@123456`, so that I can do find and replace later.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your regex was that you have used "?" marker which toggles the greediness of the "+" in your regex, so your regex "sschk@@\d+?" means "a string sschk@@ followed by 1 or more numbers, but match as less digits as possible". Removing "?" would mean "a string sschk@@ followed by 1 or more numbers (match as much digits as possible)"

Your regex statement might look like this perhaps: `sschk@@\\d{6}` and it would match a string "sschk@@" followed by exactly 6 digits. If you want to match the string "sschk@@" followed with variable length of digits, but not more than 6, you might use `sschk@@\\d{1,6}`. If you need to match any number of digits after the string "sschk@@" then use `sschk@@\\d+`

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it done.
Just apply the pattern like this

```
(sschk@@\\d+)
```